# How To Change Entire Row Background Color on Condition

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrame objects `df` and `df2` each with their own set of data. Each object has one column in particular called 'Date Time'. `df2` is a subset of `df` and I am trying to highlight the entire row where `df['Date Time'] == df2['Date Time']` as it is a huge set of data and I want to easily find where they match. I have merged both sets of data - all `df` columns and `df2` columns that I want - into `df` right now, but I removed the duplicated column in the merge and just have the remaining columns that I want in the correct row.

Here is a little code snippet of what I have:

```py
def highlight_row(rows):
    return ['background-color: green' for row in rows]

df[df['Date Time'] == df2['Date Time']].style.apply(highlight_row)
```

I'm getting an error, `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` and I'm not sure what it's referring to that isn't identically labeled or if I have a simple mistake. It should just highlight the entire row where any `df2` object is, in theory I guess for the end goal, but maybe down the line I'd need something like this conditional-wise - so I thought this could work.

As requested, here is some sample data:
`df`
|     Date Time    | Motion Detected | Alert |
| ---------------- | -------------- | ----- |
| 22-03-05 2:13:04 | False          | No    |
| 22-03-05 2:14:00 | True           | Yes   |
`df2`
| Date Time | WiFi Connection |
| --------- | --------------- |
| 22-03-05 2:14:00| Connected |

The actual data won't make any sense to you guys, so here is an example of data with a similar purpose. Basically I have - with this example data translated from my actual data - a table that looks like this in `df`:
| Date Time | Motion Detected | Alert | WiFi Connection |
| --------- | --------------- | ----- | --------------- |
| 22-03-05 2:13:04 | False | No | |
| 22-03-05 2:14:00 | True | Yes | Connected |

What I want is for any column (assume on a larger scale of data like this), where the 'Date Time' columns match (aka where there is data in 'WiFi Connection', to be highlighted a certain color.

Edit: In case the table formatting isn't showing properly, you can view the as requested information [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPZ4m.png)

Comment: Please provide some sample data for `df` and `df2` in an edit to your original question.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I just added some sample data and a more detailed explanation as to my goal if you don't mind checking it out again and seeing if you're able to offer any assistance for me!